# Do integrals $\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{\sin{x}}dx$ and $\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Do integrals $$\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{\sin{x}}dx$$ and $$\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx$$

converge?

I don't know how to solve it because we have only done comparison test, but only with $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}dx$. I don't know if you can apply it here. First thing i would do here is split them onto two integrals.

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{\sin{x}}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x}{\sin{x}}dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi \frac{x}{\sin{x}}dx$$

and 
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi \frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx$$

Comment: Use the Truncated Taylor Expansions of $\sin{x}$ to obtain inequalities which allow for direct comparison.

Comment: Hint: For $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ you have $\frac{\pi-x}{\sin(\pi-x)} \sim  \frac{\pi}{x}$ and $\frac{\pi-x}{\sqrt{\sin(\pi-x)}} \sim \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Close to $0$, $\sin x\approx x$ and close to $\pi$, $\sin x\approx\pi-x$.

Answer (score 6):

It is enough to consider the behaviour of the integrand functions at the endpoints of the integration range. $x=0$ is a removable [singularity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8p4ohy9a-_s) for both $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$ and $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}$, but while $x=\pi$ is an integrable singularity for $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}$, it is a simple pole of $\frac{x}{\sin x}$, hence a non-integrable singularity. It follows that the second integral is convergent but the first one is not. We may also notice that

$$ I_2 = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}}= \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,dx + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,dx = \pi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}}, $$
and since $\sin(x)>\frac{2x}{\pi}$ over $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ holds by concavity, we have
$$ 0< I_2 < \pi^2. $$

---

The exact value of $I_2$ can be computed through the substitution $x=\arcsin t$ and [Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):
$$\boxed{\; I_2 = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\pi\,dt}{\sqrt{t(1-t^2)}} = \frac{\pi}{2}\,B\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}.\;}$$

Comment: I don't know what integrable singularity is. We haven't gone through that. Can you explain me what is the difference between $sin x$ and $\sqrt{sin x}$ when both of them are zero at $x=\pi$

Comment: @RushThaMan: for any $\varepsilon>0$, $\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$ is finite while $\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}\frac{dx}{x}$ is not, that is the difference. Now consider that $\sin(x)$ behaves like $x$ near $x=0$ and like $\pi-x$ near $x=\pi$.

Comment: @RushThaMan: Do you know that $\int x^a dx = \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$. Now consider for which values of $a$ the limit exists for $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio can you go edit your answer into details. I am really a noob yet when it comes to convergence of improper integrals

Comment: I don't understasnd this: $I_2 = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,dx + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,dx = \pi\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}}$

Comment: @RushThaMan: apply the substitution $x\mapsto \pi-x$ in the second integral appearing after $I_2=$, then exploit $x+(\pi-x)=\pi$.